# use variable from YFM in post

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How can I use dynamic data file?
Say I have several data files: **file1.yml**, **file2.yml**, **file3.yml** and in YFM I want to tell which data file to use:

```
---
datafilename: file1
---
{{ site.data.datafilename.person.name }}
                  ^
How to tell liquid that here should be file1
```

Ideally would be to use post's file name. So that **post1.md** would use **post1.yml** data file and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work from inside a post :

```
{{ site.data[page.slug].person.name }}
```